# Passing Variables to Bootstrap Modal and Passing Them BACK

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

The variable data passed to a Bootstrap modal is hard coded in HTML data-text element field using "data-text" (according to the Bootstrap examples). If the modal's purpose is to allow a user to change that, then how do I send that back to the raw HTML data-text to update it for next time?

JS newbie here. I got Bootstrap 4 modals working and updating back to the server by Ajax (with a lot of Googling of StackOverFlow thanks!). I have about 100 text elements on the page which all load the same modal for editing of the clicked text field. The field initial value is hard coded into the page HTML in the data-text field (following the Bootstrap modal example). This allows passing of the current text value to pre-populate the modal field with the existing text value for editing.

Next, the user edits the note field in the modal and clicks submit. I am able to get the value and pass it back to the server, and update the DOM with the new edited value on the page, and everything works and looks great! So far so good.

Now here's the problem. Since I have not been able to figure out how to change the data-text field (which is hard coded in the page HTML), the screen (DOM) updates with the new value after submit correctly, but the data-text field of the element does not update. It is still the old value. It means the NEXT time I click to edit the text, the OLD value of the text field is pre-populated in the modal for editing.

Question: how do I update html data-text field by JS?

I have researched this problem at great length and without Stack Overflow I would never be able to get it working, so much appreciate you guys. Dozens of questions about passing variable TO Modals, but very few about passing the data back, and NONE about setting data-text on submit by JS.

text element definition example. This is a slightly simplified example. The text field contains some data from the server database, HTML is generated by PHP/MySQL. (1 out of 100 elements on page):

```
<td id="note_12345678" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#noteModal" data-note="<some text from db>" class="note"><same text from server db></td>
```

Here is the JS on submit code. Everything works except for the last line where I am trying to change the "data-note" field of the  element:

```
function note_submit(element) {
    var note = document.getElementById('message-text').value;
    ajaxcall("/ajaxclick.php" , { note:note } , null); // Simplified, all is working.
    noteElement = document.getElementById('note_12345678');
    noteElement.innerText = note ; // Updates the DOM with submitted note.
    noteElement.data-note = note ; // <== trying to change data-note here but obviously a syntax error.
}
```

Everything is working fine up to that last step. Clicking the text field opens modal, pre-loads the text for editing, allows the user to edit, click submit sends to server by Ajax for update, DOM note on screen is updated by JS. if I RELOAD the page, it loads the new edited text value from server db. Everything working great. Lots of joy.

Problem is NEXT time I click on the text element to edit it, the modal loads the OLD value from data-note hard coded into HTML. How to update it upon submit by JS? Thanks a million for any assistance. So close.

Updated: page is loading jquery-3.3.1.js, and bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js. Browser is FF V66.

Comment: `noteElement.dataset.note = note;` See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Examples (`noteElement.setAttribute("data-note", note);` should also work, edit: since Bootstrap requires jQuery: `$(noteElement).data("note", note);`)

Comment: @chrisG awesome thanks, I will give that a try.

Comment: You could set the "data-note" by setAttribute function. I hope this comment can help you

Comment: @chrisG jQuery solution worked! First solution did not work :(  Second solution also not working.Still old value.  I am using FF V66.

Comment: Thanks guys for really fast answers. jQuery solution is working!

Comment: @ChrisG yeah that referenced link states what you have should work. But it doesn't appear to work. Page is loading jquery-3.3.1.js, and bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: @Ramin thank you for suggestion. I did try it and it dosn't appear to work.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h6cvpfbo/

Comment: @ChrisG ok interesting thanks. Never used JSfiddle, but maybe loading jQ and Bootstrap could affect the result?

Comment: That particular fiddle doesn't use either.

Comment: @ChrisG right but my page is loading aforementioned libraries right?

Comment: Right, but still nope :) https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zxm4nsu3/ (this fiddle includes jQuery and Bootstrap)

Comment: @ChrisG coming back to this, sorry for delay, please post an answer with the three solutions and I will mark it accepted.

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to edit your question accordingly, i.e. change the title and basically remove everything besides `Question: how do I update html data-text field by JS?`